# How to use a statistic function and subsetting data simultaneously in R?

Tags: r, subset, mean

I have data that looks like this (dat)

```
region muscle    protein
head   cerebrum  78
head   cerebrum  56
head   petiole   1
head   petiole   2
tail   pectoral  3
tail   pectoral  4
```

I want to take the mean of protein values of `cerebrum`. I tried to look up different ways to subset data [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/frequently-asked-questions-about-rhow-can-i-subset-a-data-setthe-r-program-as-a-text-file-for-all-the-code-on-this-page-subsetting-is-a-very-important-component/) and [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html). But there does not seem a straightforward way of doing it. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
datcerebrum <- dat[which(dat$muscle == "cerebrum"),]
mean(datcerebrum$protein)
```

I try to condense this one line :

```
mean(dat[which(dat$muscle == "cerebrum"),])
```

But it throws out a NA with a warning that argument is not numeric or logical. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(protein ~muscle, dat, mean)
#   muscle protein
#1 cerebrum    67.0
#2 pectoral     3.5
#3  petiole     1.5
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this with the tidyverse package `dplyr`:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
fwf <- "head   cerebrum  78
head   cerebrum  56
head   petiole   1
head   petiole   2
tail   pectoral  3
tail   pectoral  4"
dat <- read_fwf(fwf, fwf_empty(fwf, col_names = c("region", "muscle", "protein")))
# The above code is just to create your data frame - please provide reproducible data!

dat %>% filter(muscle == "cerebrum") %>% summarise(m = mean(protein))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       m
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    67
```

You could even do it for every muscle at once:

```r
dat %>% group_by(muscle) %>% summarise(m = mean(protein))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     muscle     m
#>      <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 cerebrum  67.0
#> 2 pectoral   3.5
#> 3  petiole   1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution using `data.table`:**

```
# Load required library
library(data.table)
# Transform you data into a data.table object
setDT(dat)
# Subset cerebrum and mean protein values
data[muscle == "cerebrum"][, mean(protein)]
```